# End while loop missing semicolon

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I created a simple stored procedure that loops through rows of one table and inserts them into another. For some reason the `END WHILE` loop is throwing a missing semicolon error. All the code looked right to me, and all the delimiters were set up right. I just can't figure out why it would be throwing these errors, googling this problem only pointed me to improperly used delimiter answers, but nothing more. Any help would be nice!

```
USE test;
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_dropship_upload` INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  INSERT INTO `test_2` (sku, qty) VALUES(sku, qty) FROM `test_dropship_upload` LIMIT i,1;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am stuck with a problem in a large block of code and can't find where the problem is, I usually split my code in smaller chunks and test them one at a time:

**Test 1:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE testLoop()
BEGIN
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

No errors: procedure declaration and use of delimiters is OK.

**Test 2:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

No errors: the declaration of variables within the procedure is OK.

**Test 3:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_dropship_upload` INTO n;
SET i=0;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

No errors: the `SELECT` query and the variable assignment are OK.

**Test 4:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_dropship_upload` INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

No errors: the `WHILE` loop is OK.

**Test 5:**

The only untested part is now the INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO `test_2` (sku, qty) VALUES(sku, qty) FROM `test_dropship_upload` LIMIT i,1;
```

Looking a the documentation for [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) and [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html), we can see that your query is not valid: it is apparently missing a `SELECT` part and shouldn't have a `VALUES` part if you want to insert values from another table:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_dropship_upload` INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  INSERT INTO `test_2` (sku, qty) SELECT sku, qty FROM `test_dropship_upload` LIMIT i, 1;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure creation now completes without errors.

**Test 6:**

However, you will get a syntax error on the `SELECT` query when executing the procedure: MySQL doesn't accept using `LIMIT` with a variable.
To make it work, you need to use a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
PREPARE stmt FROM "INSERT INTO `test_2` (sku, qty) SELECT sku, qty FROM `test_dropship_upload` LIMIT ?, 1";
EXECUTE stmt using @i;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[It is also not allowed to used local variables in prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> Because local variables are in scope only during stored program
>   execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements
>   created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the
>   current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be
>   executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no
>   longer be in scope. For example, SELECT ... INTO local_var cannot be
>   used as a prepared statement. This restriction also applies to stored
>   procedure and function parameters.

To circumvent this problem, use a session variable `@i` instead of your local variable `i`:

**Final version of the procedure**:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testLoop`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `testLoop`()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_dropship_upload` INTO n;
SET @i=0;
WHILE @i<n DO
  PREPARE stmt FROM "INSERT INTO `test_2`(sku, qty) SELECT sku, qty FROM `test_dropship_upload` LIMIT ?, 1";
  EXECUTE stmt USING @i;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can apply the same method to debug many complex programming problems: start with a simple version of your code, test it. If it works test again with a more code, if not locate and fix the errors before continuing.